# What Should I Do When My Game Is Rejected for Not Displaying a Floating Window When No HUAWEI ID Is Signed In?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, appgallery

After my game was submitted for review, it was rejected by Huawei because the floating window is not displayed when no HUAWEI ID is signed in.
I have checked my test environment: connected to Wi-Fi, used Android and EMUI versions complying with the specifications, and used the environment in English.

Answer (score 0):

1.Use a Huawei phone running a version earlier than EMUI 9.1.1 for the test (for Huawei phones running EMUI 9.1.1 or later, HMS Core automatically displays the game floating window). Alternatively, use a non-Huawei phone (with HUAWEI AppGallery downloaded from the Huawei official website and installed) where HMS Core (APK) has been uninstalled to reproduce the problem.

2.Closely follow the instructions in the [document](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/game-buoy-0000001050121528-V5?ha_source=hms1) to call related APIs.

Call the `showFloatWindow` API in the `onResume` method and call the `hideFloatWindow` API in the `onPause` method. The `hideFloatWindow` API can be called only after the `showFloatWindow` API has been called to display the game floating window on the game UI.

3.Note that the game must call the `showFloatWindow` API immediately after initialization, instead of after a successful sign-in.